# Hard drive error 23, okay to format and use?

Tags: hard-drive

I have a hard drive that is giving a number of error 23s when I scan it. Will formatting remap the bad sectors and is it safe to use or should I throw it away?

The exact error is "The device, \Device\Harddisk1\DR1, has a bad block.." GetDataBack reports it as an error 23.

The drive is a WD Raptor.

Thank you,

Rick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hard drives are so cheap nowadays, that there really isn't a good reason to "fix" one, unless you like living on the edge and don't fear data loss.

I would NEVER use a disk that reported bad sectors, when there's one, there will be more.

Comment: Even in a raid 5 array at home?

Comment: Yep. I replace at the first signs of trouble.

Answer (score 0):

From Googleing 'error 23 hard drive' I'm guessing its CRC?

> Error 23: Data error (cyclic
>   redundancy check)

If it's cyclic redundancy check, then it's best to ditch the drive. Run a program like [HD Tune](http://www.hdtune.com/download.html) on it to view the health of the drive and also do a full error scan. If you get any red blocks on the error scan, these are bad sectors and it is best to buy a new drive.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I'll run that. I added more detail to my question too.

Answer (score 0):

Spinrite, all day long. Try it, I doubt you'll be disappointed. I've used it on multiple drives, and literally stretched years out of them by doing so.

http://www.grc.com/spinrite.htm

Comment: So you would trust the drive after running it?

Comment: Well, it's going to tell you whether or not you should, and it's going to perform all the repairs that it can. In my experience, I've used it to take drives that were showing failure indicators (SMART Tests, etc) and ran SpinRite's deeper cleaning on it, re-imaged everything back to it, and it was just about like new.

Comment: If you use the disk in a professional/server environment, don't try this, you can't trust the disk anymore. Disks are cheap, and data loss and/or downtime is expensive.

Comment: @SvenW, I couldn't agree more. This is an approach that I'd use for a consumer's drive who isn't willing to make the investment in a new drive just yet.

Comment: @JohnThePro: I would say the same for consumer drives, because I tend to value my private data and time as well, as do friends that ask for my help. But this is SF, not SU, so we are speaking about servers and stuff.

Comment: @Sven, in reality, it's exactly the same. Convince a home user that their pictures and iTunes folder isn't MORE valuable than things that run on a server? Data is data, and simplying relying on one hard drive is bad practice, regardless of consumer or enterprise market. You use the tool to extend the life of the drive, but you create redundancy. DVD backups, thumb drive, external HD, etc. Anyone who only has their stuff on one drive is begging to lose it.

Comment: Yeah, as I say: Data you have only once you don't have at all. But you were the one advocating Spinrite, when the only valid answer is to throw it away. I don't want to experience a situation where I lost data on my primary drive for whatever reason, only to find out I can't read the backup drive because I was cheap and tried to "extend it's life".

Comment: Throwing it away is not the only valid answer, I'm sorry you feel that way. I have personally used this product many times, and wouldn't bother advocating it if I didn't believe in it. I've seen it not only bring drives essentially 'back-to-life', but also being run on a regular basis can help extend the life of a drive. It's a wonderful tool, and I stand behind it.

Comment: He asked if the drive was toast, no. It's not. Sure, we'd all just go and buy a brand new drive everytime we need to if we could. But it's not the end all, be all solution.

Comment: The drive would be in a raid 5 array at home. Perhaps it is worth the risk given that I have redundancy? For a professional environment, I wouldn't even have asked the question. I would have thrown the drive away.

Comment: If you have redundancy, and you trust your data replication, give it a shot. Why not? If nothing else, you've discovered a new tool that you can use. If not, hey. On to the next day. :)